# Django auto save the current user in the model on save

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to save the user automatically when saving new data. I mean I want to save the user id for the user who is posting a new thing (submitting a form) without asking that user to choose his account from the droplist (the droplist from the User ForeignKey)

**Try 1 :**

models.py

```py
class Feedback(models.Model):
       .
       .
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False,
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.author = get_user_model().objects.get(id=2)    #############
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's working if I hard-coded the user-id `get(id=2)`. How can I make the id dynamic?

**Edit:**

**Try 2 :**

I tried also doing it with the view:

models.py

```py
class Feedback(models.Model):
       .
       .
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False,
        null=True
        blank=True
        )

    # without save()
```

views.py

```py
class FeedbackForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = "__all__"


class FeedbackListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Feedback.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FeedbackSerializer
    from_class = FeedbackForm
    permission_classes = [FeedbackPermission,]  # I also tried AllowAny

    def form_valid(self, form, FeedbackForm):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)  # I also tried self.obj = ...
        obj.author = self.request.user  # I also  tried self.obj.author = ...
        obj.save()   # I also  tried self.obj.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

But on the second try (with forms), the author field remains null.

Comment: The logic should implemented in the views or serializer/forms, not on the models

Comment: @JPG How can I add it there?

Comment: `I am trying to save the user automatically when saving new data` i can't understand your problem, you are saving your `data` inside of `user` object? and you want to save `user` object? If you save data in this object, it already means you saved this object

Comment: @JPG Not really, because the "fat model skinny view" approach has been used for a long time.

Comment: No, I meant I want to save the user id for the user who is posting a new thing (submitting a form) without asking that user to choose his account from the droplist (the droplist from the User ForeignKey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListCreateAPIView` don't have method `form_valid`, look at [this](https://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.generics/ListCreateAPIView.html)

In your `class FeedbackListView` you need to do something like this:

```
class FeedbackListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Feedback.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FeedbackSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # The request user is set as author automatically.
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```